# fallo al ejecutar una aplicacion springboot

Tags: webservice, spring-boot, build.gradle

Recurro por primera vez a la comunidad para poder resolver un problema, estoy trabajando por primera vez con servicios web con springboot y la primera vez que ejecute mi hola mundo funciono pero al volverlo a intentar, ya no me ejecuta la aplicacion, estoy trabajando con gradle

[image: o]

[image: r]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Intenta cambiar las imágenes por texto, puedes editar la pregunta y sustituir las imágenes por el texto. Puedes mirar [ask]

Comment: Lo que te sucede es que has agregado las dependencias de spring-boot para base de datos puede `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` o `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` estas dependencias se ejecutan al iniciar el proyecto por lo que te obliga a que debes tener configurada la ruta para conectar con la base de datos, encaso no quieras conectarte solo quita las dependencias, o coloca el `pom` para que que te pueda dar una respuesta más exacta.